# Java regular expression truncates string

Tags: java, regex

I have the following Java string `replaceAll` function with a regular expression that replaces with zero variables with format `${var}`:

```
String s = "( 200828.22 +400000.00 ) /  ( 2.00 + ${16!*!8!1} ) + 200828.22 + ${16!*!8!0}";
s = s.replaceAll("\\$\\{.*\\}", "0");
```

The problem is that the resulting string `s` is:

```
"( 200828.22 +400000.00 ) /  ( 2.00 + 0"
```

What's wrong with this code?

Comment: Change to `\\$\\{.*?\\}`

Comment: what's the meaning of `?` ?

Comment: Added explanation as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your regex to

```
\\$\\{.*?\\}
        ↑
```

`*` is *greedy*, the engine repeats it as many times as it can, so it matches `{`, then match everything until last token. It then begins to backtrack until it matches the last character before `}`.

For example, if you have the regex

```
\\{.*\\}
```

and the string

```
"{this is} a {test} string"
```

it'll match as follows:

- `{` matches the first `{`
- `.*` matches everything until `g` token
- the regex fails to match last `}` in the string
- it backtracks until it reaches `t`, then it can match the next `}` resulting with matching "{this is} a {test}"

In order to make it ungreedy, you should add an `?`. By doing that, it'll become lazy and stops until first `}` is encountered.

As mentioned in the comments, an alternative would be `[^}]*`. It matches anything that's *not* `}` (since it's placed in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)).

Comment: Or to avoid backtracking use `\\$\\{[^}]*\\}` (maybe `[^}]*` is little less readable than `.*?` but its performance is better).